# Forms Authentication and 400 Bad Request when redirecting from the login page using cookiless sessions and IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, forms-authentication

I have a web app configured to persist logins if the user chooses. I am using formsauthentication and set cookielesss to autodetect. When cookies are used the ticket along with specifics about the user is properly maintained. When I disable cookies, I get the session identifier embeded in the url and directed to the login page.

However, I cant get the redirect to the default page to work using IIS 7. I get 400 Bad Request - URL

When I run the application in VS Using cassini the cookieless ticket and session work great.

I have tried the following:

- set `<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="15000"/>` in web config.
- Set the Request Filtering to allow for very long URL's (1000000)

When I authenticate and redirect in VS the redirect works and the URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:53605/(X(1)S(new25hbmvxqwiupj3uijv2et)F(HHRQfdcbjBvktt0SbfNrna7jUgMQYcA2q6uv8ptwjYoQCEIO3MgYD59wXfTdRPSnzdaoCnkKQF762Tiii98dEQdmUGiAYm5XrpIcwin_TcEWMRsHDIgrqsvULetKy97--XUWx3ESMkMRWNwwYNEoC65nqvG_-ip1g0y_9N52RwspzW__QFNberHNf9asniAQv8dtFkbClW8hKyjPYawaIzmLgFw-OfCVyVyIkrjONs7nu2TZCV7sQvgG-txTtiSJ_vtBYB81vbv3n2ZSrjHsft6zyodZh0yNbRGJUc1Vb0ee4iAJQnOJ-a4Plsgx1r3qwhw_dVhkl20Omr2V81o84sfhAhd_Ye0Y4CFJk8EakQ5yRf8GNQ7gyn5Je3RWqnoAiW_gdB7VMqB7-eX4RjTml4W1RJAN2QWa7S21w-A_KrD7oc1Cp6vAOwPt_kkBxhYTApUkPIsiFQ5kJ0RnPA6NJFal9BGD9JVS9YDHZS2MHQicR-kUang362AghpexjcIDPTE1QPTEslzfpB2RnoosTPunPK5a3L0_hwSwWllagbCHxHXEA_6d73UhFeX23QYzMG_1gYFhANj7vIT5e3nDuRL_6Yep22h8tzRKAly8mk3Ke5U1_lU0sMrgdjXIInnsVzCbLfN42rUVlJaGOM1kbzM68-P9bLvu_qyD1h1iZak_coDPPNpioxg1BTQ5fyon4kSd89qAvSoDslIn3xJxwCABeY63lKoElQjel1mkusI4i1woGww_wDhS6jvFGP3R-d7xJtpTNiXsNvBc-ZIrca_XF1Z-YDnGCTy6v85vCTj-aU4xPcj7eW4CHSFwLslsBjjvNbH6UAHT5YtFW6KTlXY15_KBp79cIqOqKIOD6HRjtHijiJkgEC_BU6KPFPZh5kDH1kPX3c0wg1cFAreFM_BLje2s7MErA4kBvTwRQJMbaShFv8QOcABxLAFscw1iFBSu7QjeT0ugDblc53PCwTrlLAs5X7KTDyHgRvcGvkGKvWmFdlzD3WHLtJRlbrgDfDbYI0rWDKkR6-K2Bg--VAuUs-HBRM0FFUb0znnwaKE52Hjr39xWE1CiWmkQrcEkNhDdo-_LCnnJbXCWYiwV8rtJcFjRvISsz2w7avIJDRiGEOKw3odAL5FXztHMcLMHMuQ-wiE1LXh0FmdbSd7goHNK6Ehmoda8FP2mzN2DZEIEx887F_HO9xjQcVlHRlnECvphvBRax6jkmmJ7VUGrYLM2zH7T9MTGtuTUTASxfpvp7IYq49NhytYEieoTqDuPYVxpT7_ACywrkOZOnHUeuTvKFfDuCofE1IH_QfnB1lBk29u2qvKJMSHP5Xb1aAsZ-9_dMVIN0klVZIqvby6Khw2))/Home/Dashboard.aspx
```

When it fails in IIS the url looks like :

```
http://localhost/Reports/(X(1)S(4a0qmf3mf5ebpgokpyog0beq)F(xQGpHp6u9P7tD7I5D8uLI7zZRylqaqssOk_930NAk5VlyED4DYAk5eAC-uPOwHl5EKUrILTmQYTTIiiELL1ILCdQ5EG1gRLsIR5wSIS5_EjW0ibRstbvXVPsdSZxQOT4Uwj-JjauRvTAYNWSdff0H3mvANX8mAfUhSuMKjy67HhGJZkQjFPqUYtll0xSdP8RJ-0lMzQ-uCWG9b2OiRPT35HRk6AiuKQPDUWZNjMRzKO9-NSfm_SQXHhq8wr4xbNXuBmyDmME1lpxl3BhB_Y86KZjl_9eklFOJ-oz8_dmyuEbZqvMzXYTSfC6sL95UlRfxgXkBHRdNzLdqvMD3_1Ke78fAKEEuE6JeUbEXpES76Q6M3NJpxwz1YlEMoC_PgV9s5EQtX65QZbxzML2kSyst38Eu_WLyCL-KKE3gAmEHSUhfZ1G5WXXOoSk__vgz1Od9SNUfjxsIyEK4-HstZMLGDNWXZZc7_DTlPGrXS6yr6NfjmJEixxKEpgP-HN3Q18YPyOcS5EUwGa3tISPjGKMGq5qmZcRyihwAImUA0X5lh-rgNvWNM5AkPK8F7fAzygNJ7CZMmKN87wiCsC8kDthKZrOhbzgO4EOTsv0gEnSe7wiSH4vWzrEumUrJDGrFGLmtudyl4hLgAwQcSdMh2OIapGNVAPQTwEqwqc4kEZnWpGxXrfPxejG-IH391TFqHLyYWkN5onVXWhOn3cCeYNqD0yc7jgOZ_AY4gTj4UtiB_PAK4jlRhwyQ4SozJzkSQFimtURC-H6Z7piB6ekXIihtAdTURTpaq6CmKefCh6ydgDJNywS9nFoFBKPUdi3kF9hpuz9yNtfz8zh4LAm6ikP2p0yXBpecQq2W7V6XFJhVXC00Hvx56kvks-r1V4660-WDsvee86-4GID1XBcM7AoOWfkvABWMRDLjixk8ud57QlyJ_kYmHTeIQWDuj3EA1a6383ffycVdx3AFJ8px3eNacHybKX-9kwoYJaoo_T019ZvrcgrNWeK4uEf3VRVYVRydkJoW4Pk6OgDRN1LvSYkwEjGiN_m2g03MLfpboLMtGzorBSjTwvId8u_CqqBB4QAqj7Vt4htU6jfKWlERlqo38dTdub0i69eLAJffVoTEH2wIhqIpRp6WIWk8NNh97AkqYAOR5744cNuqJBJI56ZsY7Ja31wPArJI4nO1ey49CzReI3W5I9MWW2TuWE3x2XjFxXbea_4uTv5CdhGOYqsd5IugFMLz-0Rcva77ZI-ZipISwzv62ZXAGaQKg6PuVWIEGtTs9K_B-h3Dhg3anjxNOS7t03U6v4d9lyNwtmN4nK4-29NUAf2DcPo7V4TQzc-TtTpv-4gcvA_U47HijfasQ2))/Home/Dashboard.aspx
```

The only difference is the webdev server loads the application at the web root. I tried adding a blank test page to ensure there are no resources outside of the page being requested and it still fails.

Any suggestions?